# Limit of a power

Tags: limits

I am trying to compute this limit 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} 2^{\frac{2}{n}-1} $$ 
I calculated that the limit of the power is $-1$ so the answer to the limit is $2^{-1}$?Is this correct, because in my book it just says constant and I am not sure if they just wanted to say some constant or undefined constant.

Comment: Yep, $a^x$ will be a continuous function, so $\lim_{n \to \infty}a^{x_n}$ will go to $a^x$ if $\{x_n\} \to x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's correct, but it'd be good if you had a solid reason for it. Here's one.

Rewrite the expression as
$$
\lim \exp( (\frac{2}{n}-1) \log 2 ).
$$
Now because $\exp$ is continuous everywhere, the limit of $\exp(f(x))$ exists if the limit of $f(x)$ exists. That's a theorem, and it should appear in your text somewhere:

> If $f$ is continuous, then the limit $\lim{x\to a} f(g(x))$ exists if
>   the $\lim_{x \to a} g(x)$ exists. If that latter limit is $L$, then
>   $$\lim{x\to a} f(g(x)) = f(L).$

So we need to evaluate
$$
\lim (\frac{2}{n}-1) \log(2) = \log(2) \lim (\frac{2}{n}-1)
$$
where the equality here is by the constant rule (i.e., you can pull multiplicative constants out of a limit).

Now 
$$
\lim (\frac{2}{n}-1) = \lim \frac{2}{n}- \lim 1
$$
because both the limits on the right exist, as we shall soon see, and if that's the case, the limit of the difference is the difference of the limits.

The right-hand limit is easy -- it's just 1; the left-hand limit is (with a little work) zero. Hence
$$
\lim (\frac{2}{n}-1) = 0-1 = -1 \\
\lim (\frac{2}{n}-1) \log(2) = -\log(2)\\
\lim \exp (\frac{2}{n}-1) \log(2) = \exp(-\log(2)) = \frac{1}{\exp(\log 2)} = \frac{1}{2}. 
$$

Comment: Why a CW post??

Comment: Because there's nothing here beyond stuff that tons of folks know, and the only reason I posted it here rather than in the comments was it was a bit too long. I'm happy to take credit for my efforts, but only when I feel as if they amount to something.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that $\;\sqrt[n]a\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1\;$  for any $\;a>0\;$ , and then using arithmetic of limits:

$$2^{2/n-1}=\frac{\sqrt[n]4}2\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac12$$